# Atom can't find git, even though I have git portable

Tags: windows, git, atom-editor

I have git portable and atom. I wish to install the [Script](https://atom.io/packages/script) Package. However whenever I try to install it I get an error. I am unable to permanently add to the system's path. If needed, I already have a local copy of the package I just need to install it.

*Failed to install script because Git was not found.*

*The script package has module dependencies that cannot be installed without Git.*

*You need to install Git and add it to your path environment variable in order to install this package.*

*You can install Git by downloading, installing, and launching GitHub for Windows: https://windows.github.com*

*Run apm -v after installing Git to see what version has been detected.*

Comment: For now, I have found a website https://discuss.atom.io/t/manually-install-package/9251 which explains how to manually install a package

Comment: I have fixed it by deleting my atom folder and reinstalling it. It then worked perfectly fine with the slight exception of UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting environment variable inside terminal session, for example:

```
>cd <installer-dir>
>PATH=c:\temp\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit.7z\;%PATH%
><installer>.exe
```

The installer will then inherit the updated environment [1]

[1] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463.aspx#Inheriting_Environment_Variables

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this issue and solved it by installing Git GUI for windows. Before installing I already had Git Bash version.
Here is the [link to the download page](https://desktop.github.com/) in case you want. Happy coding !

Comment: I have git gui on my pc, but this was on a system where I did not wish to install anything and so the cause for atom portable. I have since fixed the issue.

Comment: awesome. happy coding !